# Remove items from ListBox if item exists in another ListBox

Tags: c#, listbox

I am trying to remove numerical items from a ListBox if those values exist in another ListBox. My code does not seem to work and I could not locate any help online. ListBox1 is populated by Array and ListBox2 is populated from a DataSet table (fyi).

Also for reference: I'm not adding and items to a listbox or selecting...simply just want to compare both and remove ListBox2 items from ListBox1 if they exist all automatically with a press of a button. Thank you,

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (int item in listBox1.Items)
    {
        if (listBox2.Items.Contains(item))
        {
            listBox1.Items.Remove(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it's a simple typo `foreach (int item in listBox1.Items)` try `listBox2.Items`.

Comment: just caught that...it was just a type on the forum but my code actually has listbox2.items...I just updated the code here. still no luck.

Comment: try evaluating your `if` statement to explicitly check for `true`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well you're only referencing one list box in your code - I suspect you would want:

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {

```
foreach (int item in listBox1.Items)
{
    if (listBox2.Items.Contains(item))   // notice change of reference
    {
        listBox1.Items.Remove(item);
    }
}
```

However that would cause an error since you're modifying the `ListBox` while you're iterating over it's items.  One way to safely remove items it to iterate *backwards* over the colection:

```
for (int i = listBox1.Items.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    int item = listBox1.Items[i];
    if (listBox2.Items.Contains(item))   // notice change of reference
    {
        listBox1.Items.RemoveAt(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think there's a typo in the loop condition `i == 0`, it should be `i != 0` or `i >= 0`.

Comment: Both of you are right. I set it to "i >= 0" and I also added "int item = Convert.ToInt32(listBox1.Items[i]);" and it works fine...it just skips the 1st item in the listbox.

Answer (score 2):

@D Stanley

Thank you for your help and explanation. @Yuriy - Thank you for the clarification, the

> i >= 0

works great. I also converted to listbox to int32. Below is the fully working code:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        for (int i = listBox1.Items.Count - 1; i>= 0; i--)
        {
            int item = Convert.ToInt32(listBox1.Items[i]);
            if (listBox2.Items.Contains(item))
            {
                listBox1.Items.Remove(item);
            }
        }

    }
```